# Declarar una variable en una estructura condicional en React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Estoy con una aplicación *ReactJS + TypeScript* he observado que **no se puede declarar una variable dentro de un bloque condicional**, aunque vaya a hacerse sí o sí (dentro del bloque `if` o del `else`, **debe declararse siempre previamente**, esto me impide por ejemplo *usar una constante en ciertos casos*.

Creo recordar que es igual en caso de no usar *TypeScript*.

Ejemplo inválido:

```
if (false) {
    const x = 1;
} else {
    const x = 2;
}

// Uso la variable x
```

Ejemplo válido:

```
let x;
if (false) {
    x = 1;
} else {
    x = 2;
}

// Uso la variable x
```

***Nota:** ya se que los ejemplos son muy sencillos y se puede declarar la constante asignando el valor mediante un ternario, pero no es esta la intención, este código es para ilustrar la pregunta.*

**¿Cuál es la causa de esto?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto no tiene que ver con React, se debe al funcionamiento de **let** y **const**.

**let** y **const** solamente son accesibles desde el scope en el que se declaran, en ese caso, cuando declaras una constante o variable dentro de un if se está enganchando al scope de bloque que estás creando con los brackets **{ }**, y por eso no puedes acceder a ellas desde el scope de más arriba.

Tengo un video en YouTube que se adentra más en profundidad en el tema de los scopes, te recomiendo echarle un vistazo ya que lo mismo te sirve para aclarar futuras dudas: https://youtu.be/rb20CP9qY7o